# How to mount a single file into the emptyDir of a pod

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I have found information on mounting a single file to the volume of a Pod using `configMap` or `hostPath`. But I can not find any answers related to `emptyDir`

Suppose I have a file and a directory mounted to the volumes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: launcher
        image: myImage
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /home/ubuntu/src
            name: src-volume
          - mountPath: /home/ubuntu/myfile
            name: file-volume
            subPath: myfile
      volumes:
        - name: src-volume
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: file-volume
          emptyDir: {}
```

I get the following error

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: ... not a directory: unknown
```

If the `mountPath` of the file is

```
          - mountPath: /home/ubuntu/
            name: file-volume
            subPath: myfile
```

I get an empty folder `/home/ubuntu/src`. All the files and folders added in the image are gone. Here `/home/ubuntu/` is the `WORKDIR` in the image.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  An `emptyDir:` volume is, well, empty; there won't be any files in it to mount into a container.  You shouldn't normally mount volumes over the application built into your image.

Comment: Well, it's a bit complicated to explain. I have multiple containers in a pod. I have "docker in docker" running in a pod, plus sidecars. I need an ephemeral volume, so I can share files between containers

Comment: if the files exist beforehands, mount add the corresponding volume and mount it using volumeMount in all of the containers needing them. if the files get created in a container, and needs to be shared: use an emptydir volume and mount it in every container and write the file to a location in the mountpath for them to be accessible in the other containers